# Finding Enthalpy

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

Given Information
$\ce{CH_4 + 2 O_2 -> CO_2 + 2 H_2O}$

"The Heat of reaction is $-802000\, \frac{J}{mol}$ of $\ce{CH_4}$ at $25\, ^\circ C$.
Rate of Moles of $\ce{CH_4}$ used is $0.625\, \frac{kmol}{h}$.
What is the enthalpy of reaction?"

Someone told me that the answer is $0.625 \cdot (-802000)$
But I dont get the logic behind it.

Thank you.

Comment: I am new to stack exchange so I am not sure if this kind of question is an acceptable one

Comment: I know that the formula being used is moles*H, but dont we use that formula when there is a phase change ?

Comment: for starters what is $kmol$? is that 1000 mol? Than what someone told you can't be right...

always look what unit your solution is and what units the parameters you are given are in. often oyu find the right formula by that

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.